# Draw ellipses to annotate plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

I have recently discovered matplotlib as a much better alternative to Matlab for plots. Unfortunately, my knowledge of python is close to zero.

Consider the following figure and the associated code.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=[3.3, 3.3])
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8, 'text.usetex': True})

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], color='r')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 5, 10, 17], color='r')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [11, 14, 19, 26], color='b')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [12, 15, 20, 27], color='b')

plt.annotate('blue curves', xy=(1.5, 22.5), xytext=(1.5, 22.5), ha='center', va='center')
plt.annotate('', xy=(2, 15), xytext=(1.5, 22), arrowprops=dict(width=0.1, headwidth=2, headlength=2, color='grey'))
plt.annotate('red curves', xy=(2.5, 22.5), xytext=(2.5, 22.5), ha='center', va='center')
plt.annotate('', xy=(3, 10), xytext=(2.5, 22), arrowprops=dict(width=0.1, headwidth=2, headlength=2, color='grey'))

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.savefig('filename.pdf', format='pdf')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I'd like to add a small ellipse/circle to each arrow that encloses the curves. The ellipse/circle should have the same style of the arrow (i.e., color, thicknes, etc.). Is there an easy way to do this without modifying much the existing code?

I tried to get some inspiration from [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/ellipse_demo.html) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can call `plot` and `annotate` on your `plt`-object, you will need to access the `figure` and the `axis`. A good explanation of the differences between plots, figures and axes is given [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py).

The code you will have to add (before `plt.show()`):

```
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig = plt.gcf()  # access the current figure
ax = plt.gca()   # access the current axis
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()  # get the minimum and maximum extent of the x-axis
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()  # get the minimum and maximum extent of the y-axis
aspect_ratio = fig.get_figheight() / fig.get_figwidth()  # get aspect ratio, we will use it to scale the width and height of the ellipse to appear as a circle
ax.add_patch(Ellipse(xy=(2, 15), width=(xmax-xmin)*aspect_ratio/5, height=(ymax-ymin)/5, color="grey", fill=False, lw=2))
ax.add_patch(Ellipse(xy=(3, 10), width=(xmax-xmin)*aspect_ratio/5, height=(ymax-ymin)/5, color="grey", fill=False, lw=2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Easy to extend to ellipses. Also, I was missing the differences between plots, figures and axes. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution if a circle is fine, is to add a scatter point in the position of the arrow (I don't have LaTex installed):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=[3.3, 3.3], dpi=100)
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8, 'text.usetex': False})

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], color='r')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 5, 10, 17], color='r')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [11, 14, 19, 26], color='b')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [12, 15, 20, 27], color='b')

plt.annotate('blue curves', xy=(1.5, 22.5), xytext=(1.5, 22.5), ha='center', va='center')
plt.annotate('', xy=(2, 15), xytext=(1.5, 22), arrowprops=dict(width=0.1, headwidth=2, headlength=2, color='grey'))
plt.annotate('red curves', xy=(2.5, 22.5), xytext=(2.5, 22.5), ha='center', va='center')
plt.annotate('', xy=(3, 10), xytext=(2.5, 22), arrowprops=dict(width=0.1, headwidth=2, headlength=2, color='grey'))

plt.plot(2, 15, 'o', ms=10 * 2, mec='grey', mfc='none', mew=1.5)
plt.plot(3, 10, 'o', ms=10 * 2, mec='grey', mfc='none', mew=1.5)

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.savefig('filename.pdf', format='pdf')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: smart approach ;)

Comment: Very smart indeed. However, although circles are fine for this example, I prefer to have the option to draw ellipses in general. But thanks for the quick answer :)